# Constant box2d body moving to point at a time

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I have box2d body in Andengine.I wanna move this body from (0,0) to (100,100) at a time(constant speed).How can it be possible? I tried this code: this.body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(1, 0));      but it is moving non-stop.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Do you want it to be instantly moved like a teleport, or move at constant speed? What's the problem with the body moving non-stop? Do you want it to stop moving in between? do you have gravity? Also use new Vector2(1,1) instead...

Comment: I have a body.I want it to move between (0,0)px and (100,100)px not like a teleport.I want it to move in 5 seconds(V speed or 2V speed).Not teleport.

Comment: Assuming that you do not have any gravity and linear damping of the body is set to 0 and your pixel to meter ratio is 1 a simple `body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(20, 20))` should do the job. But without more information about your scenerio nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: there is gravity.I meaned that moving body A point to B point.I tried this body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(20, 20)) .But when I use this, body continue to move to infinity..I want body to stop at a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the easiest way to move along a predefined path would be to use `Body.setTransform(...)`. This way we basically ignore all forces, friction, torque, collisions etc and set the position of the body directly.

I don't know Andengine, so this is just pseudocode:

```
public void updateGameLoop(float deltaTime) {
    Vector2 current = body.getPosition();
    Vector2 target = new Vector2(100, 100);

    if (!current.equals(target)) {
        float speed = 20f;
        Vector2 direction = target.sub(current);
        float distanceToTarget = direction.len();
        float travelDistance = speed * deltaTime;

        // the target is very close, so we set the position to the target directly
        if (distanceToTarget <= travelDistance) {
            body.setTransform(target, body.getAngle());
        } else {
            direction.nor();
            // move a bit in the target direction 
            body.setTransform(current.add(direction.mul(travelDistance)), body.getAngle());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `setTransform()` to move objects causes the simulation to not execute optimally and can cause bugs.