# Scale to a target scale without action - Cococs2d

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i have a question about scaling a `CCNode`. I want to scale a `CCNode` with a specific scalespeed in each frame until the `CCNode` reach a specific targetscale. I don't know i should start so does anyone has some pseudo code for me or some suggestions?

This is in the update method so there is the parameter `elapsedTime`:

```
float currentScale = node.scale;
float targetScale = newScale;

if(current != target){

    float scaleSpeed = 0.05f;

    //Scaling routine with elapsedTime

}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a CCScaleTo action? Combined with easing actions you can also animate the change over time.

Comment: When i use the CCScaleTo but nothing happend. I use it like this in the update method:

id action = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuraction : 0.1 scale : newScale];

[node runAction : action];

Comment: Of course if you do that in the update method it will create a new scale action every frame, so each new action overrides the previous one's results. Create it only once.

Comment: The problem is that the scale can always be changed. Could be the problem still solved with actions?

Comment: if scale changes less often than every frame, yes. You can re-run the a tion with the same key to replace the existing action already running with that key - asuming its implemented like spritekit, that i don't know.

Comment: Ok i will check this.. and yes it could be possible that the scale is changed in each frame. So it would be amazing if someone can solve the question without using actions (:

Maybe this question could help :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471504/constant-box2d-body-moving-to-point-at-a-time